# What objects should be passed to a link_to with triple nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to, nested-routes

What objects should I pass to my link_to for a triple nested route? I want to retrieve the exercise show page.

#### show.html.erb - workouts

```
<%= link_to exercise.name, plan_workout_exercise_path(???) %>
```

#### routes.rb

```
resources :plans do
 resources :workouts do
   resources :exercises
 end
end
```

#### workouts_controller.html.erb

```
def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])  
end
```

I have attempted the following, but it doesn't feed the right ID to the right model.

```
<%= link_to exercise.name, plan_workout_exercise_path(@plan, @workout, @exercise) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to get `@plan` in the show action:

In your **workout_controller.rb**:

```
def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
end
```

**In your exercise_controller.rb**:

```
def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:workout_id])
    @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
end
```

Also you can do it like this:

```
<%= link_to exercise.name, [@plan, @workout, exercise] %>
```

Recommendation: Try to get **RailsForZombies 2** slides, it has a nice section how to deal with nested routes, or just look at the guides.

Also, just for the sake of having cleaner code, get the `@plan` in the `workout_controller.rb` and `@plan` and `@workout` in the `exercise_controller.rb` with a callback function `before_filter`:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :get_plan

    def get_plan
        @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    end

    def show
        @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

And like Thomas said, try avoiding those deeply nested routes.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `exercise.name` I am assuming you are through a loop like `@workout.exercises.each do |exercise|`, right?

However, you must define the @plan in your controller.

```
def show
  @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
  @workout = @plan.workouts.find(params[:workout_id])
end
```

Then,

```
<%= link_to exercise.name, plan_workout_exercise_path(@plan, @workout, exercise)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick straight-to-the-point answer! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to avoid tripple nesting is structuring your routes like this:

```
resources :plans do
  resources :workouts, except: [:index, :show]
end

resources :workouts, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :exercises
end
```

You always get by then with just one level of nesting and much easier link helpers.

```
<%= link_to 'Create a new workout', new_plan_workout_path(@plan) %>
<%= link_to workout.name, workout_path(@workout) %>

<%= link_to 'Create a new exercise', new_workout_exercise_path(@workout) %>
<%= link_to exercise.name, workout_exercise_path(@workout, @exercise) %>
```